# SQL Count childrens from a hierarchical database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have an hierarchical database table with members like in the above array with  parents and childrens(a mlm structure/tree).

The table name is members and the fields from the table are the elements from the above array (userid, referenceid, name, surrname).

How to count all children of an userid? Lets take for example `userid = 5` has children an children have children.

I want SQL code to count for an user id all children and children-children.

Thanks!

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 3
        [referenceid] => 4
        [name] => Bandil
        [surname] => Kazim
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 1
        [referenceid] => 2
        [name] => Zarki
        [surname] => Andrew
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 5
        [referenceid] => 1
        [name] => Mirko
        [surname] => Paul
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 2390189598
        [referenceid] => 5
        [name] => Matias
        [surname] => Clark
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 4
        [referenceid] => 
        [name] => Duncan
        [surname] => Christoph
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 2
        [referenceid] => 3
        [name] => Zar
        [surname] => Jamal
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 123123
        [referenceid] => 5
        [name] => Victor
        [surname] => Dobrinski
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 9
        [referenceid] => 2390189598
        [name] => Slav
        [surname] => Jorgasen
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 4057926110
        [referenceid] => 5
        [name] => Joseph
        [surname] => Vladinski
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 10
        [referenceid] => 2390189598
        [name] => Jala
        [surname] => David
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [userid] => 7568954902
        [referenceid] => 4057926110
        [name] => ohn
        [surname] => macaron
    )
)
```

Comment: What does `refferenceid` stands for ? the id of the parent ?

Comment: Hey, yes. The refferenceid field shows the parent id.

Comment: there's no php or mysql here, just an array output generated from Lord knows what. Someone gave an answer; see that.

Answer (score 0):

If REFERENCEID is the id of the father this is one way

```
SELECT 
    REFERENCEID, COUNT(*)
FROM
    (SELECT 
         USERID, REFERENCEID 
     FROM 
         MEMBERS
     WHERE 
         REFERENCEID IS NOT NULL
     UNION
     SELECT 
         B.USERID AS USERID, A.REFERENCEID AS REFERENCEID
     FROM 
         MEMBERS A
     LEFT JOIN 
         MEMBERS B ON A.USERID = B.REFERENCEID
     WHERE 
         B.USERID IS NOT NULL AND A.REFERENCEID IS NOT NULL) TOT
GROUP BY 
    REFERENCEID;
```

The result is for each `REFERENCEID` the count of sons and nephews; if you wanna know the count of the sons and the count of the nephews group by `REFERENCEID` on both the sets used in the union.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I get this error " #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"